# Using induction to show existence of reals $|a_i|\leq 1$ such that $\sin(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)=a_1\sin x_1+a_2\sin x_2+\cdots+a_n\sin x_n$

Tags: trigonometry, induction

> Use mathematical induction to show that there exists real numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots, a_n$ such that $|a_i|\le 1$ for $i=1, 2, 3, ..., n$ and such that
> $$\sin (x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n)= a_1\sin x_1 + a_2\sin x_2 + a_3\sin x_3 + \cdots+a_n\sin x_n$$

Comment: I've tried to follow a standard induction process using sin(a+b) expansion along the way, but can't seem to get to any useful results.

Comment: What are the $x_n$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: That's exactly how I got the question, but I'm having some trouble parsing it too. Edit: the $a_i$ terms at start are a list (not sum as I mistakenly wrote before)

Comment: I think the point is just that $x_n$ is a matching unknown variable on both sides of equation.

Comment: Perhaps the idea is: *given* any particular $x_i$, one can find corresponding $a_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For $n= 1$

$\sin(x_1) = (1) \sin(x_1)$

2. Assume that $\sin(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k) = a_1 \sin(x_1) + a_2 \sin(x_2) + ...+a_k \sin(x_k)$
3. For $n = k + 1$

$\sin(x_1 + x_2 + ...+x_k + x_{k+1} ) = \sin(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k) \cos (x_{k+1}) + \cos(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k) \sin(x_{k+1}) $

Substituting step 2. and using $| \cos(\cdot) | \le 1 $, we deduce that,

$\sin(x_1 + x_2 + .... + x_{k+1}) = a_1 \sin(x_1) + a_2 \sin(x_2) + ... + a_{k+1}\sin(x_{k+1})$

This completes the proof by induction.

Comment: Ok, I think I get that. I did something very similar but kept getting myself confused on how to substitute from Step 2.

Comment: Also, I think you meant to have $sin(x_{k+1})$ at end of your sum expansion... if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Yes.  I've corrected that.  Thank you.